# Investigate the limiting behavior at the origin on the three lines $x = 0 , y = 0$ and $y = x$.

Tags: limits, solution-verification

> Investigate the limiting behavior at the origin on the three lines $x = 0 , y = 0$ and $y = x$.

For the function $f :\mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ given by

$$f(x,y)=\begin{Bmatrix} 0, \quad \{x,y\} = {0,0} \\ \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}  \quad\{x,y\}, \neq {0,0} \end{Bmatrix}$$

$$\lim_{x \to y } \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}  = \frac{x^2}{x^2+x^2} = \frac{x^2}{2x^2} =\frac{1}{2}   $$

$$ \lim_{y \to x } \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}= \frac{y^2}{y^2+y^2} = \frac{1}{2} $$

$$\lim_{x \to 0 } \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{0}{0+y^2} = 0$$
$$\lim_{y \to 0 } \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2} = \frac{x^2}{x^2} = 1$$

How's that?

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea but note that approaching along the straight line $x=0$, it is not always true that $\lim_{x,y \to 0} f(0,y) = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x,y)$. The notation is incorrect but you did arrive at the right conclusion (the limit does not exist due to differing values as we change paths).

Comment: So because the limit x=0 and y=0 differ for fort the fraction the, the does not exist.

Comment: @Patrick Yes, that is correct :-).

Comment: "The limit does not exist due to differing values as we change paths" i this a fact i need to know? Sorry i only saw this question in class and not in lectures so i have to research. 

**the limits of x and y have to be the same  when approaching the same value?**

Comment: @Patrick Yes, that is right. For the limit to exist it must equal the same value along ANY path. For that reason, checking paths only allows us to disprove that a limit exists. We cannot prove that a limit exists by checking separate paths as there are infinitely many paths.